# input field focus issue with chakra-ui

Tags: input, focus, chakra-ui

I'm building a simple form in chakra-ui with a controlled field. Whenever the user types in an input after a single keystroke focus moves to the next field.

I think there's a bug with react re-rendering the page, and the focus being "off by one" but it's a basic form and pretty frustrating! I can't see any google info on the topic but I've noticed this before when doing forms with Chakra.

The code is as simple as this, but I do have some other form elements on the same page.

docs example

- https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/form/input#controlled-input

```
    const [taskName, setTaskName] = useState('')
    const updateTaskName = event => setTaskName(event.target.value)

    <Input
        // autoFocus={false}  // no effect
        placeholder='short name for task'
        value={taskName}
        onChange={updateTaskName}
        // onBlur={evt => sanitizeTaskName(evt.target.value)}
    />
```

Is there a better way to do this, without bringing in a huge Formik type form library?

Comment: I don't get this error when I run your code.

Comment: it was missing a FormControl.